# Boundaries in 2D space

Tags: integration, plane-curves

Find the volume of figure that is bounded with the three following surfaces:$z=y^2,y=x^2,z=4$.
I don't think this has anything to do with polar coordinates etc. So I tried to put this problem in $OXY$ plane and i get parabola $y=x^2$ and $y=0$ but not sure how to read boundaries, because here(in $OXY$) we don't have that some area is closed, only that is bounded with parabola and x-axis, but not sure how to know boundaries for x,y from that. If someone knows how to proceed following example in this way I would be happy to know.

Comment: Seems the region is 3 dimensional so it doesn't make sense to try to g3t volume by looking only at XY plane.

Comment: I had similiar example, where I needed to find the volume bounded with $z=x^2+y^2,z=2x^2+2y^2,y=x,y=x^2$. And in solutions was written that $x^2+y^2\le z\le 2x^2+2y^2$ and for x,y they got bounds from XY plane.

Comment: Well in $y,z$ plane the region between $z=y^2$ and $z=4$ is a bounded piece of that plane (do a sketch), and maybe by throwing in the $y=x^2$ condition somehow could get what the 3-d region is...

Comment: Yes, i guess. I get $0\le y\le 4, y^2\le z\le 4$. Is this correct for YZ plane? And what about x, can I say $-\sqrt{y}\le x\le \sqrt{y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given $z$, your surface will be bound by:

$-\sqrt y \leq x \leq \sqrt y \,$ (by parabolic cylinder $y = x^2$)

$0 \leq y \leq \sqrt z \,$ (by parabolic cylinder $z = y^2$).

Bound of $z$ is $0 \leq z \leq 4$.

Integrate in order $dx$ first, $dy$ next and $dz$ last.

EDIT: Here is the integral

$\displaystyle \int_0^4 \bigg [\int_0^{\sqrt {z}} \bigg[\int_{-\sqrt {y}}^{\sqrt{y}} dx\bigg] \, dy \bigg]\, dz$

And the sketch at any given $z \,$:

[image]

You can also change the order of integration by writing the limits differently.

Comment: First, thank you for the answer. Then I am not sure for order of integration you have used. If we watch area that is bounded below with $y^2$ and from above with $z=4$, and from the left and right side with $y=0,y=2$ we get $0\le y\le 2, y^2\le z\le 4$. If this is correct, than I should do integration in order $dx, dy, dz$ right? And we have done on your way than it should be $dx,dz,dy$?

Comment: Let me first add a $2D$ sketch if that helps. I will then respond.

Comment: If you integrate wrt to $z$ first then yes your limits for $z$ are correct. Then what are you integrating with respect to next?

Comment: Yes, i thought to integrate first on z, then on y, and last on x. Is it?

Comment: You can do both. I have integrated over $x$ first then $y$ and $z$ last. What I have done is looked at the surface at any $z$. It is really area of the parabala $y = x^2$ with upper bound of $y$ coming from parabola $z = y^2$.

Comment: If you are doing $y$ after $z$, your bound of $z$ is correct but $y$ has to be bound below by $x^2$. You have mentioned upper bound correctly as $2$.

Comment: And for $y = 2$, $-\sqrt2 \leq x \leq \sqrt2$.

Comment: Right, I get it now. You fixed z, and then got bounds in xy plane. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You are welcome! Not this particular problem but there are some that are easy to do in one specific order and then you say, how I would do it in different order. That helps a lot in long run.

Answer (score 1):

$z=4$ and $z=y^2$ intersection projection gives lines $y=\pm 2$ on $OXY$ which together with $y=x^2$ gives figure on $OXY$. Then integral is
$$\int\limits_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{x^2}^{2}\int\limits_{y^2}^{4}dzdydx$$

[image]